# Flow to update a custom Lead check box field based on a custom check box field being checked on an Account where the Lead is associated to the Account

Tags: visual-workflow

I assign Leads to Account and I'd like to update a custom field checkbox on each lead assigned to an account based on a custom field check box being checked on the Account the Lead is associated with.

I have tried to use Flow but it is failing to update the records.

[image: Floe]

[image: Configure Start]

[image: Edit Update Records]

Comment: what do you see when you debug the flow?

Comment: Find all Lead records where

Account_Name__c Contains {!$Record.Account Name}
Update the records’ field values.
Lead_Market_2D_OVR__c = true
Result

Info
Failed to update records that meet the filter criteria.

Comment: Info
Error Occurred:

This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: Account_Name__c FROM Lead WHERE ((Account_Name__c LIKE '%{!$Record.Account ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:46 invalid operator on id field. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Comment: Account_Name__c is an Account Lookup Field

Comment: if `Account_Name__c` is a lookup field, then it needs to be compared against a field of type `Id` (Like $Record.Id)

Comment: That was it, thank you cropredy

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments, `Account_Name__c` is a lookup field. Hence, for purposes of Flow, it is a field of type `Id`

Hence, it must be compared against a field on `Account` that is also an Id. The most likely field to use would be `$Record.Id` (i.e., the triggering account's Id)